# Ruby-on-Rails Voting Partial Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, voting

I have a voting feature on my app but can't route back to the same page with the vote applied. I know I have to fill in the link_to methods but my understanding of routing/ruby syntax is a bit limited, so I'm not even sure [post, vote] is correct. I feel I'm missing something else as well. Have I even provided enough information? How should I approach this problem? Or better yet, how can I understand routing better from this? Thank you.

Here is the the error I'm getting: 

`No route matches [GET] "/posts/13/up-vote"`

My voting partial:

```
<% if policy( Vote.new ).create? %>
  <div class="vote-arrows pull-left">
    <div>
      <%= link_to [post, vote],
        post_up_vote_path(post),
        class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up #{(current_user.voted(post) && current_user.voted(post).up_vote?) ? 'voted' : '' }" %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong><%= post.points %></strong>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= link_to [post, vote],
        post_down_vote_path(post),
        class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down #{(current_user.voted(post) && current_user.voted(post).down_vote?) ? 'voted' : '' }" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my routes.rb

```
   Bloccit::Application.routes.draw do

      devise_for :users
      resources :users, only: [:update]

      resources :topics do
        resources :posts, except: [:index]
      end

      resources :posts, only: [] do
        resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
        resources :favorites, only: [:create, :destroy]
        post '/up-vote' => 'votes#up_vote', as: :up_vote
        post '/down-vote' => 'votes#down_vote', as: :down_vote
      end

      get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

      root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: paste your routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the error message: `No route matches [GET] "/posts/13/up-vote"`. It's looking for a `[GET]` route, but you've defined a `[POST]` route in your `config/routes.rb` file.

You need to add `method: :post` to both of your `link_to` helpers in order to trigger a `[POST]` request. Here's what it would look like:

`<%= link_to [post, vote], post_down_vote_path(post), class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down #{(current_user.voted(post) && current_user.voted(post).down_vote?) ? 'voted' : '' }", method: :post %>`

Hope this helps!